# Kinesis : EXCEPTION: SocketException: Operation not permitted (select/poll failed)

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I keep getting this error `EXCEPTION: SocketException: Operation not permitted (select/poll failed)` when I push frames to kinesis, this is followed by

```
f-stream is reported. Terminating...
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Exception while sending data.
ERROR / KinesisVideo: 2018-06-09T16:26Z T31: EXCEPTION: RuntimeException: Exception thrown on sending thread: Exception while sending encoded chunk in MKV stream ! 
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: PutFrame index: 10, pts: 15285616115400000, dts: 15285616115400000, duration: 200000, keyFrame: false, flags: 0
com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.ProducerException: Failed to put a frame into the stream.

at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.putKinesisVideoFrame(Native Method)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.putFrame(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:440)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerStream.putFrame(NativeKinesisVideoProducerStream.java:259)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.mediasource.ProducerStreamSink.onFrame(ProducerStreamSink.java:35)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesis.custom.S3FileMediaSource.putFrame(S3FileMediaSource.java:114)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesis.custom.S3FileMediaSource.access$3(S3FileMediaSource.java:112)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesis.custom.S3FileMediaSource$1.onFrameDataAvailable(S3FileMediaSource.java:103)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesis.custom.S3FrameSource.generateFrameAndNotifyListener(S3FrameSource.java:84)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesis.custom.S3FrameSource.access$0(S3FrameSource.java:71)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesis.custom.S3FrameSource$1.run(S3FrameSource.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Received all data, close
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Closing data stream
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Stream unblocked notification.
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Data availability notification. Upload handle: 0, Size: 0, Duration 0
DEBUG / KinesisVideo: Being notified to close stream streamName with uploadHandle 0
INFO / KinesisVideo: End-of-stream is reported. Terminating...
```

can't figure out why this is happening, any ideas ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same exact error message

Comment: finally we used the PutMedia API instead, to insert MKV, but we could find that the above error was due to ending connection with Kinesis for the below 2 reasons
1- sending wrong fragments (order/time)
2- ending thread before finishing the Kinesis connection establishment

I would recommend to try your logic on EC2 instance or generally standalone application (JAR) and check the logs

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with AWS Lambda. I believe the lambda is quitting mid-execution of the socket transmission which is causing this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we used the PutMedia API instead, to insert MKV, but we could find that the above error was due to ending connection with Kinesis for the below 2 reasons

1. sending wrong fragments (order/time)
2. ending thread before finishing the Kinesis connection establishment

I would recommend to try your logic on EC2 instance or generally standalone application (JAR) and check the logs